# A column in MySQL should automatically hash an inserted value (Using Hibernate and Java)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have some Objects in Java, using hibernate, for example:

```
@Entity
class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String pw;

    public User() {}

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}
    public String getPw() { return pw; }
    public void setPw(String pw) { this.pw = pw; }
}
```

When I instantiate a new User Object, I hash a String manually like this

```
User user1 = new User();
user1.setPw(hashPw("MyPassword"));
```

It works fine, but what I want is to use the setter just like

```
user1.setPw("MyPassword")
```

And I want the Database to automatically hash the String with the SHA-512 algorithm (Or any you would recommend which can also be used in Java).

I would like to tell the database when it gets created, that this column has to be hashed.

I built the database completely with hibernate, which I'm new to.
ATM I save the hashes in a char(128) column, not nullable, using utf8 character set.

EDIT:

Best would be a way with annotations in hibernate/jpa in the java code.

EDIT:

First step in my application is to fill the database with data. After that, I will only use the objects, maybe without changing any of their values ever again, so I need the hashing step when I insert the real data (test data atm) for the first time. I already tried the Formula annotation like this:

```
// ...
@Formula("SHA2(pw,512)")
private String pw;
// ...
```

but after that, the column was missing complete.

EDIT:

I'll try to show how I imagine a possible solution:

1. Instantiate a new User Object user1
2. Set UNHASHED password like user1.setUnhashedPassword("MyPassword");
3. Open a new Session
4. Begin Transaction
5. Save Object user1
6. end transaction
7. close session
8. Getting data from database
9. Print column "Hashed_Password"

All this, without having any hashing logic in my java code.

Comment: What about interceptor to hash before save http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/events.html

Comment: You should look for "@PrePersist" and "@PreUpdate" annotations. Using those you can make sure that everytime your entity is persistted on the database the desired columns get hashed.

Comment: Okay I took a look at the `PrePersist` and `PreUpdate` Annotation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html), but there it is used on a transient attribute, but I will try it.

Comment: You should check the definition of `@Formula`, because you totally misunderstood its use case. Btw there are special hash algorithms for passwords like [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: `@PrePersist` should be okay, but `@PreUpdate` might cause problems.  For instance, you don't want to rehash the user's password when they update their name/email address.  Another option is to add a `@Transient` method like `setPwPlaintext(String plaintext)` that does the hash and then sets the persistent property accordingly.  An `Interceptor` is way overkill, I agree.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing `public void setPw(String pw) { this.pw = hashPw(pw); }`

Comment: @MikeNakis I thought about this, but that isn't the purpose of a Setter Method, because the value of the getter should be the same than the one you set. It would work, but it is a bad programming style and shouldn't be done.

Comment: True, I totally agree.  But you can't have it both ways: both set the unhashed password, and somehow (magically?) end up with a hashed password.  So, here is what I would recommend: `@Column private String hashedPassword;` `public String hashMyPassword( String unhashedPassword );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of the fact that you are dealing with both hashed and unhashed passwords in the same class, you have to have a clear distinction between what is a hashed password and what is an unhashed password.

A column defined as `@Column private String pw;` is a bad idea, because it begs the questions: what is this?  Is this a hashed password, or an unhashed password?  What will `getPw()` return?  What will happen if I invoke `setPw( "mypassword" );`?

So, refrain from using an identifier called just "password", always use identifiers like "hashedPassword" and "unhashedPassword".

So, I would recommend the following:

```
@Column 
private String hashedPassword; 

public String getHashedPassword() 
{
    return hashedPassword;
}

public void setHashedPassword( String hashedPassword ) 
{
    this.hashedPassword = hashedPassword;
} 

public String setUnhashedPassword( String unhashedPassword ) //no getter!
{
    String temp = hashPw( unhashedPassword );
    setHashedPassword( temp );
}
```

Comment: My code at the top is just a minimalistic example, because that is not what my question is about (sorry about that chaos, first question here). The code I'm using is clearly named. The question is, is it possible to do this hashing at the database/hibernate site, when inserting a value or saving an object using hibernate. I will edit my post and write an example how I imagine it.

Comment: I think I understand already. But then my recommendation would be "never use magic to do something that can just as easily be accomplished without magic".

Comment: What @MikeNakis said.  The hashing is a simple operation.  Moreover, doing it at the "hibernate side" is _essentially the same thing_ as building it into the setter in your `Entity` class.  To do it at the database side you'd need to use either native queries or (more likely) custom triggers in your database.  But then your solution becomes dependent upon having a particular database provider.  Is that what you want, or would you rather have portable code that can be used with _any_ database provider that hibernate can talk to?  Most of the time portable code is more valuable than db magic.

Comment: Ah okay now I understand your points thank you. Okay yeah normally I would prefer portable Code, but in this particular project I think we only use the mysql database I will build up once. But when I think about it, I guess it would be more secure when I hash the password in the code, because than the hash will be send to the DB instead of the plain text which will hashed after sending it to the DB and maybe it will go through internet later. BUT, only for my own knowledge, I still would like to know, how I can use the triggers in this case for my "problem".